# Magento 1.5.1 doesn't show subcategories

Tags: magento, categories, visible

Good day everyone!

I have a problem with my multi-store Magento.

Magento version 1.5.1

I created a new rootcategory, with categories "Men" and "Women" and "Men" contains 2 subcategories, wich not show up.

All the rootcategories including every category inside is setting to Active, enabled "Included in Navigation Menu" and also set to Anchor.

Men and Women are still visible, but the 2 subcatgories in Men don't show up anywhere.

Also printed the Array with every information about the categories, but the 2 subcategories in Men are not in this array.

Note: Cache is disabled.

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend, go to System > Configuration.

In the Catalog Tab, you have "Category Top Navigation". Check that the Maximal Depth is set to 0 or is greater than 3.